# What is Formula Definition in the Entity Definition and how is it useful to run a report or SOQL query

Tags: tooling-api

I would like to know the logic added in the formula field. With the standard/custom reports I can get the list of formula fields created on one entity like case/account/custom objects however to check the actual logic written in the formula I need to run a query on field definition with the metadata for only to the single field of the respective object. Here is the example query by which I can read the formula logic at the metadata.formula field

```
Select developername,datatype,entitydefinition.developername,metadata 
 from fielddefinition 
 where (entitydefinitionid='Case')and 
        datatype like 'formula%' and 
        developername = 'SDO_Service_Urgency'
```

[image]

but if I run the query without developername condition then this is the error message I am getting

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: When retrieving results with Metadata or FullName fields, 
the query qualificatio​ns must specify no more than one row for retrieval. 
Result size: 25
```

Can you please explain to me what that error means? is there a way that we can get the logic of the formula used at the org/object level from API? I also searched for the formulavariable documentation but I don't see anything related.

Comment: the error is telling you have 25 formula fields on Case and queries that return the `Metadata` column can only return 1 row

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the error message

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: When retrieving results with Metadata or FullName fields, 
the query qualificatio​ns must specify no more than one row for retrieval. 
Result size: 25
```

Your query does include the `Metadata` field, documented in the [Tooling API FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm?q=fielddefinition).

```
Select developername,datatype,entitydefinition.developername,metadata 
  from fielddefinition
```

> Query this field only if the query result contains no more than one record. Otherwise, an error is returned. If more than one record exists, use multiple queries to retrieve the records. This limit protects performance.

Since the error message states `Result size: 25` and you are filtering on formula fields, you have been told that you have 25 formula fields on `Case`. Thus, using this form of the query, you can not get all the formula field expressions in one query.  Imagine you didn't filter on `EntityDefinitionId` or `DataType` - the results coming back would be huge and hence a likely explanation for the design limit.

A brute force workaround would be to get the 25 fields in one query, then loop through each one querying the `Metadata` field one query per `FieldDefinition.DeveloperName`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate if you can suggest if there is any alternative to get the formula logic for all the formula fields exist in the object.

Comment: @LalithaPavaniRallabandi - I suggested a brute force workaround = it will require code